# How to repeat animation forever in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I want to repeat an animation forever in my view. Below is my code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
        delay:0.49f
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
        animations:^{
        //for IMMERSE
        [_pic2 setAlpha:1.0f];
         _view1_immerse=_pic2.frame;
         _view1_immerse.origin.x = ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-_view1_immerse.size.width)/2;
         self.pic2.frame=_view1_immerse;
         }
         completion:^(BOOL finished){
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0.49f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
         _view1_immerse=_pic2.frame;
         _view1_immerse.origin.x = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
         self.pic2.frame=_view1_immerse;
         [_pic2 setAlpha:0.0];
         } completion:^(BOOL finished){
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0f animations:^{
         _view1_immerse=_pic2.frame;
         _view1_immerse.origin.x = -_view1_immerse.size.width;
         self.pic2.frame=_view1_immerse;
                                     }];
                                 }];
                             }];
```

I tried adding option `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat`, but it seems that it only repeats the "animation" part of the most outside layer. I want to repeat the whole set of animation.

And I do not want to use `NSTimer`.
Could anyone give me some advice about my problem?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put your `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` on the inner animations instead of the upper animation. If that doesn't work, use keyframe animations instead.

Answer (score 31):

You can check below code for repeat animation.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                  delay:0.0f
                options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
             animations: ^(void){self.view.center = CGPointMake(0, 200);}
             completion:NULL];
```

Thanks

**Swift 4**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 100,
                   delay: 0,
                   options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .beginFromCurrentState],
                   animations: {

    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Any ideas how to stop it after some time?

Comment: `[view.layer removeAllAnimations]`