# How to create looped animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-animation

How to create looped animation?
I'm running this code and animation is executed 1 time:

```
CAAnimationGroup *animationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
[animationGroup setDuration:0.4];
CABasicAnimation *firstAnimationLayer;
CABasicAnimation *secondAnimationLayer;
firstAnimationLayer = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"startPoint"];
firstAnimationLayer.autoreverses = YES;
[firstAnimationLayer setRepeatCount:20];
[firstAnimationLayer setRepeatDuration:0.3];
[firstAnimationLayer setFromValue: [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)]];
[firstAnimationLayer setToValue: [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0)]];
[firstAnimationLayer setDuration: 0.4];
[firstAnimationLayer setBeginTime:0.0];

secondAnimationLayer = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"endPoint"];
secondAnimationLayer.autoreverses = YES;
[secondAnimationLayer setRepeatCount:20];
[secondAnimationLayer setRepeatDuration:0.3];
[secondAnimationLayer setFromValue: [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0)]];
[secondAnimationLayer setToValue: [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1)]];
[secondAnimationLayer setDuration: 0.4];
[secondAnimationLayer setBeginTime:0.0];
[animationGroup setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstAnimationLayer, secondAnimationLayer, nil]];
[self.gradient addAnimation: animationGroup forKey:nil];
```

I want to create animation for my gradient and looped that.

Comment: equivalent of repeatCount = .infinity

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730460/how-to-make-uiview-animation-sequence-repeat-and-autoreverse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544334/how-to-represent-infinity-in-objective-c

Comment: @AhmadF
it didn't help(
my animation is executed once

Comment: [refer this ans i hope it will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31421505/8385972)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[firstAnimationLayer setRepeatCount: INFINITY];
[secondAnimationLayer setRepeatCount: INFINITY];
```

Comment: it didn't help(